# xml binding in asp.net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have been trying to send XML in asp.net core method via jquery ajax. This is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([FromBody]string model)
{
     return Json(true);
}
```

And the below is my jquery ajax request:

```
var encoder = new mxCodec();
var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
var model = mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node);
mxUtils.popup(model, true);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Graphs/Save/",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf8",
        dataType:"xml",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
});
```

This is the sample xml text:

```
"<mxGraphModel>\n  <root>\n    <mxCell id=\"0\"/>\n    <mxCell id=\"1\" parent=\"0\"/>\n  </root>\n</mxGraphModel>\n"
```

But the model parameter shows null always.

Answer (score 0):

Your requset contentType is set to "text/xml; charset=utf8",but request body format is set to json by "JSON.stringify(model)",try to remove JSON.stringify and try again.

Comment: Nope. I did this but doesn't work.
`$.ajax({
        url: "/Graphs/Save/",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf8",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: model,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

For `FromBody`, it will read request from request body and the `content-type` should be `application/json`, try make a test with code below:

```
        var model = "<mxGraphModel>\n  <root>\n    <mxCell id=\"0\"/>\n    <mxCell id=\"1\" parent=\"0\"/>\n  </root>\n</mxGraphModel>\n";
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44307/api/JsonInput/Save",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```